# JIRA: Searching for all issues with a given link type

Tags: search, jira, issue-tracking, jql

Is there a way to query for all issues with a particular link type?

For example, let there be a dependency link where an issue can "depends on" another issue. Is there a query to find all issues that depend on some other issue (aka. all issues with the "depends on" link)?

I know there is the *linkedIssues* (*key*, *linkType*) function that returns the key of all issues that have the *linkType* with the issue with *key*. I want to find all issues with a *linkType* with any issue.

Thanks!

Comment: It's possible with Jira4 (tested on 4.2.4) issue in linkedIssues(ABC-123) issue in linkedIssues(ABC-123,"depends on") See
[Manual page](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA042/Advanced+Searching?clicked=jirahelp#AdvancedSearching-linkedIssues)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can hack it with [Craftware JQL](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/org.craftforge.jira.craftforge-jql-functions-plugin)'s linkedIssuesFromFilter, where the filter would be "all issues"

Comment: The free Script Runner add-on will be a better option for most as it is freeware and heavily supported.  See answer below from @nico-gawenda.

Comment: unfortunately Script Runner is no longer free :(

Answer (score 18):

You can use [Script Runner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner) plugin - Edit: It unfortunately is no longer free. The last version before 4.0 still is, though. Details here https://www.adaptavist.com/doco/display/SFJ/Downgrade+ScriptRunner

It sports a ton of incredibly useful functions, one of these is [hasLinks()](https://jamieechlin.atlassian.net/wiki/display/GRV/Scripted+JQL+Functions#ScriptedJQLFunctions-hasLinkType(linktypename))

Usage example:

```
issueFunction in hasLinks("blocks") OR issueFunction in hasLinks("is blocked by")
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Script Runner is very robust and free.

Answer (score 2):

The included function mentioned by Alexander is ideal for its purpose but if you want something more advanced check out the commercial JQL Tricks plugin: https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/JQLT/Issue+Link+Functions

Answer (score 2):

If you need a JIRA On-Demand solution - you might find this **paid** [Add-On](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/jql-pro) useful

It exposes MongoDB syntax and some conditions builder UI, so you should be able to search for the issues:

- linkedIssuesHaveStatus([status])
- subtasksHaveStatus([status])
- linkType([linkType])
- workBetween([started|created|updated], [from], [to])